# Pair an ESP32 to an HC-05 BT module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, microcontroller, esp32, hc-05

I want to set an ESP32 microcontroller as master and make him connect to a HC-05 bt module. I am using the examples **SerialToSerialBTM.ino** of the Arduino IDE,but if put the MAC address of the Bluetooth Module it print *"connected successfully"* in the Serial Monitor and then it print this error and the ESP32 reset itself and restart.

```
Stack smashing protect failure!

abort() was called at PC 0x400d5ee8 on core 0

Backtrace: 0x4009194c:0x3ffcfb30 0x40091b7d:0x3ffcfb50 0x400d5ee8:0x3ffcfb70 0x400fe443:0x3ffcfb90 0x400f58d2:0x3ffcfbe0 0x4008e0bd:0x3ffcfc10
```

If I put a casual MAC address it  always print *"connected succesfully"*,but it doesn't restart. The code that I use in the Arduino IDE is this, can anyone tell me more about this error and how can I make my code work?

```cpp
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

String MACadd = "98:D3:32:11:31:37";
uint8_t address[6]  = {0x98, 0xD3, 0x32, 0x11, 0x31, 0x37};
//uint8_t address[6]  = {0x11, 0x1D, 0xA5, 0x02, 0xC3, 0x22};
String name = "HC-05";
char *pin = "1234"; //<- standard pin would be provided by default
bool connected;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test", true); 
  SerialBT.setPin(pin);
  Serial.println("The device started in master mode, make sure remote BT device is on!"); 

  connected = SerialBT.connect(address);

  if(connected) {
    Serial.println("Connected Succesfully!");
  } else {
    while(!SerialBT.connected(10000)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect. Make sure remote device is available and in range, then restart app."); 
    }
  }
  // disconnect() may take upto 10 secs max
  if (SerialBT.disconnect()) {
    Serial.println("Disconnected Succesfully!");
  }
  // this would reconnect to the name(will use address, if resolved) or address used with connect(name/address).
  SerialBT.connect();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: If you don't get any good answers here, you can also try arduino.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
connected = SerialBT.connect(address)
```

try like this

```
connected = SerialBT.connect(name)
```